# When mounting using docker, bind source path does not exist

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

When trying to mount using docker, I tried all sorts of things like restarting docker and using different directories.

```
MacBook-Pro:user$ sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 
--mount type=bind,
source=/user/Documents/Repo/models/userCategorization/saved_model/,target=/models/saved_model 
-e MODEL_NAME=saved_model 
-t tensorflow/serving

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": 
bind source path does not exist: /user/Documents/Repo/models/userCategorization/saved_model/.
```

Wanted to add that "Users/" directory is indeed in the file sharing preferences and the directory for the model file would be "Users/user/Documents/..etc".

Comment: Are you sure that the source directory actually exists? Docker won't create that for you and typos in the directory path are usually the reason. I suggest you try with the full absolute path of the source directory (the one that appears with `pwd` in terminal)

Comment: @FarzadVertigo If the source directory is local, then yes it does exist. I'm not sure what you mean by the pwd in terminal, I'm still a noobie when it comes to terminal commands.

Comment: @FarzadVertigo I just tried the pwd in terminal and it gives me the same error.

Comment: So you can navigate to the directory with `cd /user/Documents/Repo/models/userCategorization/saved_model/` in terminal without any problem?

Comment: Your comment made me realize that I was not actually inputting the directory correctly. Now that I solved that thanks to you, I'm getting another error that says
```Console
Could not find base path /models/saved_model for servable saved_model
```
So I'm not sure exactly what input docker is expecting?
userCategorization/ is where the saved_model is but as for target, I don't know what to place there.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out:

My first issue was that I was not targeting the correct directory, such as `/model_folder`

My second issue was that I was that I did not have a specific version in the model folder such ash
`/model_folder/1/`